# What does [literal] in [array/object] mean?

Tags: javascript

What does the following syntax mean:

```
1 in [1,2,3,5]
```

I know it doesn't search for 1 in the array. But what does it do?

I've seen it used in loops:

```
for (var i in testArray)
{

}
```

But have also seen this used by itself. Does it mean check if the literal is a valid index in the array or object that is the other operand?

Comment: [MDN - `in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/in)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*literal*`in`*object* means: "Get a property *literal* from *object*."

When used in a loop, the engine will try to access all properties of the *object*.

`1 in [1,2,3,4]` doesn't check for an occurence of an element with a value of `1`, but it checks whether element 1 (`array[1]`) exists or not.

Answer (score 3):

Very simply, [it's an object property search](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/in):

```
print ('a' in {'a':1, 'b': 2}); // true
print ('c' in {'a':1, 'b': 2}); // false
```

[Live demo.](http://www.ideone.com/ck0oP)

This is subtly different to [the similar use of `in` in `for` loops](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in).

---

**Also note that it should *not* be used with arrays, although this is a common error to make.**

It is unspecified what properties besides numeric keys make up the internals of an array, so you should stick to the Array API (e.g. [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)) if you're using Arrays, otherwise you'll end up with [behaviour that you may not expect](http://www.ideone.com/3Kt7R):

```
print ('length' in [1,2,3,4]); // true
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a cheap way not to use a traditional `for` loop for each item in the array.

Your 2nd example is a for-each loop. It doesn't have the literal `1` (one).

Answer (score 1):

It's used to iterate JavaScript objects.

This loop will iterate through each "key" in the object.

Its common usage is iterate through such objects:

```
var Car = { color: "blue", price: 20000 };
for (var key in Car)
    console.log("Propery " + key + " of Car is: " + Car[key]);
```

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/XgE2T/) - check Chrome/Firefox JavaScript console to see the output.

When used for plain arrays, each "key" will be the index.. for example:

```
var nums = [20, 15, 30]
for (var key in nums)
    console.log("Propery " + key + " of array is: " + nums[key]);
```

Will show the keys as 0, 1 and 2. [Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XgE2T/1/) for such case.

Answer (score 1):

'in' operator returns true if specified property exists in specified object; used in a loop it allows you to iterate over all properties of the object